What does "labore" mean in this passage of Hugh of Saint Victor?
To be precise, I'm aware labore is generally translated as work, but I'd like to know if it's to be understood as physical work, intellectual work or any kind of work in the following passage of Hugh of Saint Victor:

Ingenium a natura proficiscitur, usu juvatur, immoderato labore retunditur, et temperato acuitur exercitio.

Additional context: this comes from "De modo Discendi et Meditandi", written in the 12th century (I assume).

While it does more often refer to physical exertion, it can be used metaphorically, including mental labor, deeds, hardships, and even literary activity.
To me it seems best to read this as a metaphorical use of the term. A word doesn't have to regularly be used metaphorically for it be possible to be used as so by someone, and physical abductors regularly get used to metaphorically refer to mental ones. It's why in English "mental gymnastics" became a set phrase.
Reading labor here metaphorically has some support in the De Septem Septenis:

Cavillosa vero disputatio ingenium exercendo excitat, in qua si moram fecerit obtundit et fascinat.


A captivating discussion excites the intellect by exercising it, in which, if it wastes time, dulls and bewitches it.

It seems to me to mean that excessive discussion blunts ingenium, and the verb here (obtundit) has the same root as Hugh's (retunditur)
On the other hand, a more literal reading absolutely also makes sense. He might very well be saying that some physical activity is good for the intellect (temperato...exercitio), but toiling away (immoderato labore) is harmful instead. To me, at least, both options are valid. It would potentially take a wider reading of Hugh to draw more definite conclusions.

Thank you for your answer. It's because both interpretations make sense that I wondered which one was correct. However, if we were to assume that both exercitio and labore refer to the same kind of activity, I think it is best to assume Hugh speaks of intellectual work. What immediately follows the quote I provided is "Memoria per exercitium retinendi et assidue meditandi maxime juvatur et viget", where exercitium is almost certainly not physical since it appears as exercitium retinendi et assidue meditandi and  meditandi is clearly not physical. I should've provided that in the OP.
